# Set property in an entity when it is initialized using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to set a property when an entity is initialized on the first time. When the `uid` is set first, the property  `uuid` should also be set from the same id but as a string.

I used this code thinking that the `setUid(Long value)` method would also set `uuid` attribute when the entity class is initialized.

```
@Entity
public class LogUser {

  @Transient
  private String uuid;   
  @Id
  private Long uid;

  public Long getUid() {
    return uid;
  }

  public void setUid(Long value) {
      this.uid = value;
      this.uuid = value + "";
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seems to work. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your Hibernate/JPA annotations are on the fields, Hibernate completely ignores your accessor methods and directly modifies the fields. The easy fix, then, is to move those annotations to the accessor methods (they go on the getters). This will make Hibernate use your setter, triggering its side effect. However, you have to do this for *every* field in the class - you can't mix field and accessor use within a class - and this may cause problems if you ever put logic in your accessors that you don't want Hibernate to trigger.

Another way would be to null check and lazily initialize in the getter specifically for the transient field, like this:

```
public String getUuid() {
    if (uuid == null) {
        uuid = uid + "";
    }
    return uuid;
}
```

Finally, if you want to keep Hibernate on field access and insist that it must be initialized eagerly, you could look into making a custom [Tuplizer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/tuple/Tuplizer.html) for the class. You'd probably want a subclass of [PojoEntityTuplizer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/tuple/entity/PojoEntityTuplizer.html), overriding `afterInitialize()`. Use the [Tuplizer annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Tuplizer.html) on the entity class to associate your custom tuplizer with it.

Comment: +1 for Tuplizer. I didn't know that. And also the get method hack is also great. I think it would be enough for this implementation. I wanted to use the entity id when I'm using JAXB. So no cyclic errors would occur. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you juste use a constructor where you define :

```
public LogUser(long uid){
    this.uid = uid;
    this.uuid = uid.toString();
}
```

Or maybe I didn't understand ?

Comment: I want it to be set when retrieved after a persistence query. Not when I'm initializing in the object. I think you misunderstood it. Thanks.